# Minecraft TestFor command help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using the testifier command, `/testfor @a[x=-436,y=9,z=-758]`, but instead of testing for a player at those coordinates, it is testing everywhere, and finding me. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Your command does not work as supplying a `x`, `y` and `z` modifier only changes the location of which the command block detects from.

If you'd like to detect for a player at that location, add the `r` (radius) modifier to your selector.
By default, the radius (if one is not specified) is infinite (also called 'none').

You'll want to use:

```
/testfor @a[x=-436,y=9,z=-758,r=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use execute:

`execute @a -436 9 758 [command you want to happen]`

This command makes a player execute the command you put when they go to the location you entered [-436 9 758].